# Js filter array object by array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have the following array.

Array original:

```
var array =[
  { "id": 1, "name": "abc", "gender": "m","age": "15" },
  { "id": 2, "name": "a", "gender": "m", "age": "25"  },
  { "id": 3,"name": "efg", "gender": "f","age": "5" },
  { "id": 4,"name": "hjk","gender": "m","age": "35" },
  {  "id": 5, "name": "ikly","gender": "m","age": "41" },
  { "id": 6, "name": "ert", "gender": "f", "age": "30" },
  { "id": 7, "name": "qwe", "gender": "f", "age": "31" },
  { "id":8, "name": "bdd",  "gender": "m", "age": " 8" }
];
```

Array remove:

```
var arrayCopy =[
  { "id": 1, "name": "abc", "gender": "m","age": "15" },
  { "id": 3,"name": "efg", "gender": "f","age": "5" },
  { "id": 7, "name": "qwe", "gender": "f", "age": "31" },
  { "id":8, "name": "bdd",  "gender": "m", "age": " 8" }
];
```

I have to remove the elements in the original array that are contained in the remove array, but I'm having some problems.

I thought of taking all the ids from the array copy and then doing the exclusion, but I'm not so sure it's the best method.

Some advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) of ids to exclude from `arrayCopy`. You can then filter the array, and keep all items with ids that don't appear in the Set:

```js
const array = [{"id":1,"name":"abc","gender":"m","age":"15"},{"id":2,"name":"a","gender":"m","age":"25"},{"id":3,"name":"efg","gender":"f","age":"5"},{"id":4,"name":"hjk","gender":"m","age":"35"},{"id":5,"name":"ikly","gender":"m","age":"41"},{"id":6,"name":"ert","gender":"f","age":"30"},{"id":7,"name":"qwe","gender":"f","age":"31"},{"id":8,"name":"bdd","gender":"m","age":" 8"}];
const arrayCopy = [{"id":1,"name":"abc","gender":"m","age":"15"},{"id":3,"name":"efg","gender":"f","age":"5"},{"id":7,"name":"qwe","gender":"f","age":"31"},{"id":8,"name":"bdd","gender":"m","age":" 8"}];

const idsToExclude = new Set(arrayCopy.map(({ id }) => id));

const result = array.filter(({ id }) => !idsToExclude.has(id));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I thought of taking all the ids from the array copy and then doing the exclusion...

Yes, that's probably the best way. Store them in a `Set` (ES2015+) or an object as properties (e.g., `ids[id] = true`), and then use `filter` on your original array, only keeping the entries whose IDs are not in the set/object.

Alternately, if the arrays are short(ish), you could use `filter` on the outer array and then `some` on the "remove" array to determine whether it has the outer array entry's ID. That means traversing the "remove" array repeatedly (once for each entry in the outer array), but for smallish arrays that's not a problem.